# vote_counts = md[md['vote_count'].notnull()]['vote_count'].astype('int')

Tags: pandas, notnull

How this is working?
I know the intuition behind it that given movie_dataset(using panda we have loaded it in "md" and we are finding those rows in 'votecount' which are not null and converting them to int.

but i am not understanding the syntax.

Comment: Refer [How to ask good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use `md.loc[md['vote_count'].notnull(), 'vote_count'].astype(int)` to prevent index chaining which is generally a bad idea in pandas.  How it works is better explained with this statement, the first arg to loc is a boolean series created where vote_count is not null.  The second arg to loc is what column to return then cast that return as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

`md[md['vote_count'].notnull()]` returns a filtered view of your current `md` dataframe where `vote_count` is not NULL. Which is being set to the variable `vote_counts` This is [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

```
# Assume this dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('ABC'))
df.loc[2,'B'] = np.nan
```

when you do `df['B'].notnull()` it will return a boolean vector which can be used to filter your data where the value is True

```
df['B'].notnull()

0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: B, dtype: bool


df[df['B'].notnull()]

         A          B           C
0   -0.516625   -0.596213   -0.035508
1   0.450260    1.123950    -0.317217
3   0.405783    0.497761    -1.759510
4   0.307594    -0.357566   0.279341
```